# How to take n input in java according to the value of test cases?

Tags: java

How can we take n input in java according to value of T

Like if i take t=2,then we take two n input

If value of t=3,then we take three n input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
         int t=s.nextInt();

         int n=s.nextInt();
         int n=s.nextInt();

         int evensum=0;

         for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
             if(i%2==0) {
                 evensum=evensum+i;
             }
             System.out.print(evensum);
         }
    }
```

As in this code i take t=2 and I take two n inputs.
If I take t=3, then what how could I take that third input?

Comment: You can't have multiple variables with the same name. make an array or a list to store your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple variable with the same name, for your purpose use a loop :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many values ?");
int nbInput = s.nextInt();
for (int i = 1; i <= nbInput; i++) {
    int input = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print(input);
}
```